# Create a list in python3

Tags: python, list, range

It may be a basic question, but there are things I do not understand. I would like to create a list from 0 to 99, but it will not be output as I expected.

```
list = range(5)

print(list)
# >>> range(0, 5)
```

I want to get the following list.

```
print(list)

# >>>[0,1,2,3,4,,...,98,99]
```

Comment: google list comprehensions in python. I think that's what you are trying to get ;)

Comment: `list(range(100))` will do it, see the dupe

Comment: `[i for i in range(0, 100)]`

Comment: `list(range(100))` is all you need

Answer (score -2):

try this code:

```
list1 = []
for i in range(100):
    list1.append(i)
print (list1)
#print list for python 2.7
```

Comment: 1. `list` shouldn't be a name for a variable
2. List comprehensions wold make it easier:
l = [i for i in range(100)]

Comment: Or just `list(range(100))`, but of course that only works if `list` is not redefined as some variable.